# Android SDK - List All Users

Tags: android

I have just begun working with the Android SDK and I am having problems with my first app.  Currently, I am trying to list all of the users in a big list.  However, no matter what I try, the app continues to force close.  I found the code in the sample files, but this is still giving me issues.  Below is the code I am using.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                People._ID,
                People._COUNT,
                People.NAME,
                People.NUMBER
             };

        //Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
        Uri contacts =  People.CONTENT_URI;

        //Make the query. 
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts,
                    projection, // Which columns to return 
                    null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                    // Put the results in ascending order by name
                    People.NAME + " ASC");      

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME};
        int[] names = new int[] {R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
          R.layout.main, c, columns, names);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

This is directly from the sample file, yet it still errors out.  I have found that the line that causes the problem is the "Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts," line.  Has anyone else out there seen this?  I am at a loss and have not found any solutions after 2 hours or research.

Also, I have added the following line to my app's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Thanks, and if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the example from the SDK docs is out of date.  Try getting rid of the `People._COUNT` column from the cursor projection.

It's probably causing an `IllegalArgumentException` (see the output from `adb logcat`)