# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _count error while retrieving contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, illegalargumentexception

I am working on a project where I need to list down all the contacts. I am following [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

My **AndroidManifest.xml** contains below, so i can read the contacts:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**Code is here**:

```
private void getContacts() {
    try {
        // Form an array specifying which columns to return. 
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                                    People._ID,
                                    People._COUNT,
                                    People.NAME,
                                    People.NUMBER};
        
        // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
        Uri contacts =  People.CONTENT_URI;
        
        // Make the query. 
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts,
                                    projection, // Which columns to return 
                                    null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                                    null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                                    // Put the results in ascending order by name
                                    People.NAME + " ASC");
                
        printContacts(managedCursor);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Contacts",ex.toString());
    }
}

private void printContacts(Cursor cur){ 
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String name; 
        String phoneNumber; 
        int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME); 
        int phoneColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);
        String imagePath; 
    
        do {
            // Get the field values
            name = cur.getString(nameColumn);
            phoneNumber = cur.getString(phoneColumn);
            Log.d("Contacts","Name: "+ name + " **** Phone: "+ phoneNumber);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

When I run it on the Emulator(2.3.3) it throws below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _count
```

Can someone fix it?
Great thanks for your valuable time & help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the string People._COUNT everything works

See also: [Android SDK - List All Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620231/android-sdk-list-all-users)

Answer (score 1):

Android [People](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html) class is deprecated. You should use [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) instead.
Since you run it on Emulator API level 10, and the class is deprecated since API level 5, there's no reason to keep using People.